# Conservation of energy when ball is carried down a hill

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

> When a football rolls down a hill, the potential energy of the ball turns into kinetic
> energy at the bottom. However, if you carry the ball down and stand with it at the
> bottom, the ball has no kinetic energy. Explain what has happened to the energy.

I am completely stuck on this one. Any ideas?

This isn't a homework question...

Comment: Consider if the ball weighs 500 pounds, and the person who "carries" it needs to resist the force of the ball all the way down.

Comment: Hi user1488. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the gravitational potential energy of the ball has been converted into heat in the leg and arm muscles of the person carrying the ball downhill.

Comment: this makes much more sense,

Answer (score -1):

When a person carried a ball to the bottom, the ball got a force from that person. So, you've got displacement (the ball moved from the top to the bottom) and you've got force. Remember what is force times displacement? Yes, that is work. For F constant, work is W = F x s (F is force and s is displacement). So, the work was there to cancel the kinetic energy that supposed to be produced if the ball rolls.

Comment: I understand, but to what has the GPE of the ball been transferred? The person is doing work, but this is additional energy being inputted to the system. The GPE of the ball is not being transferred to work done - that wouldn't even make sense, because the work is being done by an outsider, not by the ball.

Comment: The work is negative. The force is upward and the displacement is downward. So, you've got negative work. @user1488

Comment: @user1488 By the way, I think I understand your confusion. You might think that work is something that is similar to the word "work" in our usual conversation. I think in physics, you should just use the exact definition of work, which is the mathematical definition. In physics, work is just done by a force, not a thing (not a ball or not a person). In this case, the work done to cancel KE. Similar to what can be done by a friction force when a moving box losing it's KE because of the friction, the work is negative.